# Does Javascript (V8) optimizes unused return values

Tags: javascript, v8

Let's say we have a function like so:

```js
function foo() {
  // do some work...
  return () => {}; // foo returns a function
}
```

The client code can use `foo` in two scenarios:

1. Use the result of the function

```js
const result = foo();
// some code that uses result...
```

2. Ignore the result of the function

```js
foo();
```

I wonder if the runtime (I don't want to refer to the language itself because it's likely that this is implementation-dependent) will optimize the 1rst case so I don't have to do it myself like this:

```js
function foo(needTheResultValue = false) {
  // do some work...
  if (needTheResultValue) return () => {};
  // nothing is returned if the caller didn't ask for it
}
```

Comment: pretty sure it does, but you shouldn't be worried about it as this is unlikely to impact the performance of your app, the code in "2." is completely valid

Comment: Is there some measured cost to creating the return value that you'd like to avoid? Is this code on a hot-path? If not, just return something every time and let the caller choose to ignore the returned value.

Comment: the more I think about it, the more I convince myself that doing it manually is a premature optimization in 99% of the cases (when the result if not too expensive to compute)

Comment: @rareyesdev Yes, it is. ^^

Comment: Does it matter for your question that the return value is a function object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 developer here. The short answer is "it depends, don't worry about it".

In general, V8 (and other engines, as far as I'm aware) optimizes on a per-function basis. So, in your example, if and when `foo` is optimized, it doesn't know whether its return value will be used or ignored, so it can't optimize it away.

The exception to this is inlining: the optimizing compiler has the ability to inline called functions when the calling function is optimized, e.g. in this example:

```
function foo() {
  // Do some FOO work...
  return {};
}
function bar() {
  foo();
  // Do some BAR work...
}
```

When `foo` is optimized, it will (continue to) return a freshly allocated empty object, regardless of where it's called from. When `bar` is optimized, the compiler might decide to inline `foo`, and after that step it sees (its own internal representation of a hypothetical function like):

```
function bar() {
  // Do some FOO work...
  {};
  // Do some BAR work...
}
```

And then it can easily drop the unused object allocation in there.

That said, as comments on the question have pointed out, this isn't something you need to worry about. (Unless if you happen to needlessly spend huge amounts of time constructing expensive but unused return values -- but that seems unlikely, because it's a fairly obvious inefficiency, so chances are you wouldn't write such code in the first place.)

In particular, returning some value that you have computed anyway has **zero** cost compared to returning nothing, because every function always returns something -- if it doesn't have a `return` statement, then the engine will quietly insert a `return undefined;` for you. That means `function f1() {}` and `function f2() { return undefined; }` will compile to exactly the same code. And if you decided to write something like:

```
function overly_clever(need_result) {
  let result = do_some_work();
  if (result < 0) handle_error();

  if (need_result) {
    return result;
  } else {
    // Return nothing.
  }
}
```

Then that function would be ever so slightly (not measurably) *slower* than if you replaced everything after the empty line with a simple `return result`, because the "empty" `else`-branch (with its automatically inserted `return undefined;`) is no faster than `return result`, so evaluating the `need_result` condition is a waste of time.

So, in short: don't worry about it. Write code that makes sense, let the engine take care of optimizing it.

(For completeness: if you do feel a need to do manual optimization work, let it be guided by measuring: profile your app to see where most time is being spent, and measure the effects of any attempted changes to see if they are effective. Don't use microbenchmarks, because they tend to be misleading.)